# The second same assertation doesn't work in Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am writing a code that will check the names of the dropbox menus. With the first one it works fine, but for the others it shows me this error,  even thought the dropbox is visible. I didn't change the code, so it's the same for all menus.
This error appears:

> AssertionError
> Timed out retrying after 5000ms: expected '' to be 'visible'
> This element  is not visible because it has CSS property: display: none

My code:

```
 it('Check the dropdown menu Onboarding', function () {

    cy.visit('http://localhost:25000/', { timeout: 300000 })
    cy.wait(10000)
    cy.get('.dijitReset.dijitInline.dijitMenuItemLabel.dijitMenuItem:eq(1)').click() 
    cy.contains('Smartcard zuweisen').should('be.visible')
    cy.contains('Primäre Smartcard zuweisen').should('be.visible')
    cy.contains('Primäre Karte drucken und zuweisen').should('be.visible')
    cy.get('.dijitReset.dijitInline.dijitMenuItemLabel.dijitMenuItem:eq(1)').click() 
 
  })


it('Check the dropdown menu Kartenverwaltung', function () {
    //cy.visit('http://localhost:25000/', { timeout: 300000 })
    cy.wait(10000)
    cy.get('.dijitReset.dijitInline.dijitMenuItemLabel.dijitMenuItem:eq(2)').click()
    //cy.contains('Kartenverwaltung').should('be.visible')  
    cy.contains('Aktive und deaktivierte Karten')
    cy.contains('Karteninventar').should('be.visible')
    cy.contains('Personenübersicht').should('be.visible')
    cy.contains('Follow You Printing').should('be.visible')
    cy.contains('Staging-Tabelle').should('be.visible')
    cy.contains('Ausstehende Karten').should('be.visible')
    cy.contains('Gesperrte Karten').should('be.visible')
    cy.contains('Karte zurückgeben').should('be.visible')
    
})
```

The first function **Onboarding** works. From the second function **Kartenverwaltung** appears the error. What could be the problem?

[image]

First 3 tr and their children:
[image]

Update:
In the dropdown that doesn't work with 'td' :
[image]

Error:
[image]

Comment: I'd also like to ask why `cy.get('.dijitReset.dijitInline.dijitMenuItemLabel.dijitMenuItem:eq(1)').click()` a second time at the end of the first test? To close the menus? What happens when you `cy.visit` in the second test, does the problem go away?

Comment: @AloysiusParker thanks for your answer! I added the Inspect the menu. this is the list of the down dropbox and I see that for example under 'Aktive und Deaktivierte Karten' it says display:none. But it's written the same for the first 'Onboarding' there for each in the list it's also written dispay:none.
2. And for the 2nd question I was checking different variation, and yes exactly that was to close the menu and it didn't help, same as if I add cy.visit in the second test too.

Comment: Can you post the html as text? Maybe just the first 3 <tr> and their children. It looks like each row <tr> has 3 cells <td> - the first is an icon, the 2nd is the text that is visible to the user, and the 3rd is an accelerator key that has `display: none` (but I bet it has a event handler for keypress).

Comment: I tried to add the html as a text, but it didn't work for some reasons so I added text. I hope it's okay.

Comment: Cool, so same pattern as before. It looks like Cypress is getting confused - the <td> with content "Karteninventar" has no `style="display:none"` attribute, that's on the next <td>. Maybe it has selected the <tr> above, since `cy.contains(myText)` will search through all children for 'myText'. I would try a more targeted command specifying the element as well: `cy.contains('td', 'Karteninventar').should('be.visible')`

Comment: @AloysiusParker thanks with 'td'  it helped and it works now for Karteinventar and others in the same dropdown list. But for the others it doesn't work and in the error it's written that it cannot be visible because it's a parent. I will update my question with the tr of the other dropdown list. And what is interesting that with addind 'td' works and with the others doesn't. Moreover, it doesn't work with the one where in the end is written Remote. I tried to compare but for now I don't see the difference or what is different in there compare html wothout remote.

Comment: So, looks like this is menus #3 - did you close menus #2 with `cy.get('.dijitReset.dijitInline.dijitMenuItemLabel.dijitMenuItem:eq(2)').click()` in the previous test?

Comment: I checked with closing the menu, but it doesn't really matter if I close or I don't close. The previous test with 'td' works without closing. Do u have any other options to try?

Comment: Yeah, I think it's possible to fix this but not without being able to see the DOM in text format. The pictures are not matching up with the error message - the error shows `MenuItem_18` but the screenshot only goes as far as `MenuItem_16`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is my best guess at how to do this based on all the info given. I advise you to take a data-driven approach, which assumes all menus have the same pattern (which may not be true, I can't say for sure).

There are some gaps in the menu data that you will have to fill out from the app iteslf,

```js
describe('Check the menus', () => {

  const menus = [
    {
      number: 1
      name: "Onboarding".
      items: [
        'Smartcard zuweisen', 
        'Primäre Smartcard zuweisen',
        'Primäre Karte drucken und zuweisen',
      ]
     },
     {
       number: 2
       name: "Kartenverwaltung".
       items: [
         'Aktive und deaktivierte Karten', 
         // other items here
       ]
     },
     // other menus here
  ];

  menus.forEach(menu => {

    it(`Check the dropdown menu ${menu.name}`, function () {
      cy.visit('http://localhost:25000/', { timeout: 300000 })
      cy.wait(10000)
      cy.get('.dijitReset.dijitInline.dijitMenuItemLabel.dijitMenuItem')
        .eq(menu.number).click();                                 // open menu
      cy.get(`table[title="${menu.name}"]`).should('be.visible'); // confirm opened
      menu.items.forEach(item => {
        cy.contains('td', item).should('be.visible');  // Confirm items
      };
  });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
This element is not visible because it has CSS property: display: none
```

The above line tells us that the element is not visible but it exists in the DOM. One way to assert is you can use `exist` instead of `be.visible`. It will validate that the element exists in HTML DOM.

```
cy.contains('Karteninventar').should('exist')
```

Or, If you have elements that are visible after scrolling you can use [scrollTo()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/scrollto.html#Syntax) to go to that element and then use `should(be.visible)`

eg.

```
cy.scrollTo(0, 500)  //Scrolls down
cy.contains('Karteninventar').should('be.visible')
```

Or, If you want to directly assert the element with the property with `display: none` you can do something like:

```
cy.get('#dijit_MenuItem_3_accel')
    .should('have.attr', 'style', 'display: none')
```

Comment: @pavelsaman Thank you ! With 'exist' it worked. But when the test is running I see that the element is visible, but for some reasons the cypress doesn't see it. Do you know by any chance what could be the problem?

Comment: @PolinaLisetska The web apps css should change to `display: block` or some other css if the element is visible or there might be some other reason that this is kept like this. In any case `exist` should work fine or if you want to check that the element has the style attribute as `display: none`, you can do that as well, I have updated my answer.

Comment: How does `cy.contains('Karteninventar').should('exist')` do anything different to `cy.contains('Karteninventar')`?

Comment: @Ackroydd True I just saw the document which states - Get the DOM element containing the text. DOM elements can contain more than the desired text and still match.